# Troubling creating subdirectory of NSCachesDirectory and adding image to it

Tags: ios, ios5, nsfilemanager

**EDIT: Solution at the end of the post**

I'm having trouble creating a subdirectory of NSCachesDirectory and adding an NSData object to it. I've referred to multiple SO posts related to this but when I debug my code, it tells me that the NSData file in the folder doesn't exist. My code:

```
NSURL *photoURL = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:self.singlePhotoDictionary
                                          format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
    NSData *URLToData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:photoURL];

    NSString *cacheDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *newDirectory = [cacheDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Photos"];

    BOOL isDir = NO;
    NSError *error;
    if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:newDirectory isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir == NO)
      {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath:newDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
      }

    NSString *filePath = [newDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"thePhotos.jpg"];
    NSLog(@"%@", filePath);

        //[URLToData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:URLToData attributes:nil];
    NSData *theData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filePath];
    NSArray *contentsInManager = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:newDirectory error:nil];
```

theData and contentsInManager turn out to be:

```
theData NSData *    0x00000000

contentsInManager       NSArray *        0x00000000
```

Any help here? The subdirectory exists but the file won't be created inside of it.

As a side question: When do we need to make our own instance of NSFileManager as opposed to using the defaultManager?

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION: After trial and error, I tried deleting the subdirectory and recreating it. Once I did, the file was able to write to the subdirectory.**

Comment: What is the value of `URLToData`?  Seems like the file could fail to create if that were `nil`.  Also, regarding when you might not use `defaultManager`, from the documentation: "You might do this in situations where you want to associate a delegate with the file manager to receive notifications about the status of file-related operations.".

Comment: @KevinGrant URLToData has the data for the photo obtained from NSURL. The problem isn't the chance that it might be nil because my test cases all have working NSData objects and are able to be written to NSCachesDirectory but not a subdirectory of it. After fumbling around I was able to get it to work by removing the subdirectory and recreating it. Strange but it works now.